# detection of height doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have this simple script:

```
var o = document.getElementById("content");

if (o.clientHeight == "372") {
  o.style.height = "328px";
  o.style.marginBottom = "44px";

} else {
  o.style.height = "214px";
  o.style.marginBottom = "32px";
}
```

but somehow the ELSE always executes, even if the initial height of my div is 372px...
can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the div have any padding?

Comment: You should look at what the value of clientHeight is in either a debugger or an alert statement and use that as your first clue why the else statement is executing?

Comment: Yes@jfriend00 - Also, keep in mind that different browsers calculate different heights for different objects. For example: The default height for a button in IE is 17, but in Firefox it is 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientHeight` takes padding into account. You may want to use `scrollHeight`, `offsetHeight`, or `style.height`, depending on your needs. Note that `style.height` does not return an integer like the others.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php

Answer (score -1):

if `clientHeight` does return integer, try to remove quotes like this:

```
var o = document.getElementById("content");
    if(o.clientHeight==372){
    o.style.height="328px";
    o.style.marginBottom="44px";}
    else{o.style.height="214px";
    o.style.marginBottom="32px";}
```

Comment: clientHeight returns an integer